# Asp.NET MVC4 Redirect(url) throwing argument exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This seems impossible, I'm sure there is something very simple I am missing, but I just don't see it.

Inside of an action method I have this code

```
   var redirectUrl = FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(model.UserName, false);

   if (redirectUrl.IsBlank())
   {
       return RedirectToRoute(Routes.HomeUrl);
   }
   else
   {
       return Redirect(redirectUrl);
   }
```

And IsBlank() is implemented

```
  public static bool IsBlank(this string s)
  {
      return String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s);
  }
```

Somehow though

```
POST /login?ReturnUrl=
UserName=xxxx&Password=xxxx
```

manages to product this error

```
ArgumentException: Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: url]
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Redirect(String url) +113
   WebHost.Controllers.SecurityController.Login(LoginModel model) +200
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +104
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +182
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +24
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +99
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9629296
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: I am able to fix this by adding logging statements to trace the value of return url, I can only guess that something is being optimized away :/

Answer (score 0):

I think an action needs to be redirected to an action, rather than a simple URL.

Try something like this:

```
Response.Redirect(Url.RouteUrl(new{ controller="controller", action="action"}));
```

Comment: Not true, `return Redirect(url)` is perfectly valid.

Comment: is Home.Url being set when you are in debugging?

Comment: Yes, public const string HomeUrl = "home";

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var redirectUrl = FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(model.UserName, false);

if ( Url.IsLocalUrl(redirectUrl) )   
{
    return Redirect(redirectUrl);
}
else
{
    return RedirectToRoute(Routes.HomeUrl);
}
```